# What is the difference between desire and papa and punya?

Tags: sin, punyam, desire

what is the difference between desire and punya and papa. Punya and papa also seems to be a desire because i like to give good things to that person which means i am
desiring good things should be given to that person. Similarly papa also seems to be a desire.

Comment: Just a little peek on desire, you can [read here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/78308/what-can-gods-be-afraid-of/78348#78348).

Comment: If I am not wrong, punya is a quanification of good you do. Similarly paapa is for bad. The desire to do good will also confer punya but doing good unwillingly will also give punya(little lesser than the former). Hence these three are connected and not the same.